# Did the Tomb Raider (Lara Croft) actually raid tombs?

Tags: lara-croft-tomb-raider

I haven't played the games, but watching *Lara Croft Tomb Raider: The Cradle of Life* film, I don't recall her raiding any actual **tombs** (defined in the dictionary a vault *designed for burying the dead*).

So, **did the Tomb Raider (Lara Croft) actually raid tombs?** Especially in the film part of the franchise?

Comment: In the games, including the recent-ish reboot of the series, she typically starts out/is portrayed as an archaeologist, and yes she visits many many tombs.

Comment: Yes, she's only raiding the tombs in the same sense that Indiana Jones could be considered a tomb raider.  They're doing the "raiding" more for fame and archaeology than greed.

Comment: @DVK - Oh well, when one thinks of traditional "raiders", its usually implied that they are "raiding" for spoils and thus direct economic gain.  In this manner Indiana Jones and Lora Croft differ from traditional raiders.  Your asking if they are actually "raiding" the tombs and so it becomes an issue of semantics on one level.  Let me know if you need further context.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Lara Croft did "raid tombs": obviously so in the games, and likely so in the movies.

First off, for what it's worth, the name "tomb raider" is used in the movies more than once:

> You're the tomb raider, figure it out!
>
> One tomb raider is good, two... better.

The term, though, seems to be used more in the sense of "person who explores ruins of dead civilizations", perhaps using a more metaphorical sense of the word "tomb". Lara Croft (like Indiana Jones) is nominally an archaeologist. She explores the remnant of old civilizations, which would include the sites of very old cities, temporary settlements, etc. Many civilizations built extravagant burial sites, so those are a favorite target for archaeological research.

Off-screen, it's likely that she spent a good portion of her time in such burial vaults. For example, the first film opens with her "practicing" her skills in a simulated tomb; presumably, she wouldn't have chosen such a setup if she didn't expect to spend lots of time in tombs in the future.

However, there are a few instances in the movies where Lara does go into what you might argue is an actual tomb. In *Lara Croft: Tomb Raider* she recovers artifacts from a tomb in Angkor Wat and another in a ruined city in Siberia. While Angkor Wat itself isn't a tomb so much as a temple, the specific room where the artifact is is *named* as a tomb by the locals:

> "Lara, do you remember the jasmine that only grows in one temple on the ancient Khmer trail in Cambodia? That is the entrance to the Tomb Of The Dancing Light, where the first half of the triangle is hidden.

(The tomb in Siberia isn't ever named as anything except "ruined city" but it seems to be a burial chamber with the usual blockbuster-movie-style extravagances added.)

In the video game series it's more clear-cut. Several games, including *Tomb Raider*, *Tomb Raider: The Last Revelation*, and *Tomb Raider: Anniversary* involve exploration of a genuine tomb; the other games in the series are set in, for example, the catacombs beneath the Great Wall of China, or other similar archaeologically interesting non-tomb locations. It's true that as the series progresses, it becomes less about exploring tombs and more of a general "clandestine artifact hunt", but the general idea of an action/adventure archaeologist still mostly carries through.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to imply that it counted as a tomb; it does serve as indication that she likely spends time off-screen in tombs, since she chose that location for her practices. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: If you have a cite (script, or image) for the Siberia tomb, it'll be an accepted answer. Angkor Wat is borderline... I tend to consider it not a tomb since that wasn't its primary purpose but that's murky

Comment: The "tomb" in Siberia is also more of a temple that happens to have lots of people buried in it, so if you're iffy on Angkor Wat you'll be iffy on that too. I'm looking for a legit script to see if anyone in the movie calls it a "tomb". (Wikipedia did but that's about it)

Comment: "That is the entrance to the Tomb Of The Dancing Light, where the first half of the triangle is hidden." [from the transcript](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=lara-croft-tomb-raider)

Comment: Archaeologists seem to have an avid interest in ancient garbage pits, but I guess "Raiders Of The Lost Garbage Dump" wouldn't have the same panache.

Comment: Might be worth updating this to include that the entire plot of the latest film is essentially just raiding Himiko's tomb.